# Tab's Disapper When I place my Logo on to the Navbar

Tags: html

I am very confused about a situation I have with my Website's Code. The Problem is that when I add my logo into the Navbar, it makes tab which are aligned to the right of the navbar disappear.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
  <link href="animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho&effect=shadow-multiple">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho&effect=outline">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho&effect= ice">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Rendered-Homepage</title>
</head>

<style>
  .body {
    font-family: Jura, serif;
  }
  
  .navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0;
    /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    z-index: 999;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="Rendered" style="">

    <!--Navigation Bar-->

    <div class="Navigation">
      <nav class="navbar " style="height: 65px; background-color: #ffffff;; font:Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Franklin Gothic Bold', 'Arial Black', 'sans-serif'; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 100%; ;">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <!--Rendered - Logo-->

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Images/Rendered-Logo-(Version-2).png" alt="Rendered-Logo" style="width: 10%; height: auto; margin-right: 0;"></a>
          </div>

          <!--Navigation Bar Tabs-->

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-left: 0; padding: 5px; font-size: 15px; color: black;">
            <li><a href="#">Couses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I know that the code is not the cleanest and I apologise for it. 
I would really appreciate it if someone told me why I have having this problem and How could I solve it.
Regards
[image: This is the Problem - When I add my logo, the Tabs disappear.]

[image: This is without the logo.]

Comment: `.navbar-header` is displaying as a block, which pushes anything else in the container onto the next line. Have a look at `inline-block` (For both the logo and the tab container)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion DBS but could you please show me exactly what do I have to change/add. I am really confused and I I seem to have forgotten how to do such thing's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the "Courses" and "Community" tabs. They only disappear if your screen is less than 768 px.

To preserve it you can try:

```css
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .body {
            font-family: Jura, serif;
        }

        .navbar {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            position: fixed;
            /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
            top: 0;
            /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
            width: 100%;
            /* Full width */
            z-index: 999;
        }

    }
```

to put them in one line try placing in a container:

```html
                <!--Navigation Bar Tabs-->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto" style="margin-left: 0; padding: 5px; font-size: 15px; color: black;">
                        <li><a href="#">Couses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kyrul. But It seems that the tabs are underneath the navbar. I have tried setting the overflow to visible and suddenly they appear on the line below. And it seems that even when my logo's width is only 10%, it is talking up the entire width of the navbar. Any Ideas?

Comment: so you are saying you want the logo and tabs on the same line right?

Comment: Ok Great Now they Both on the Same Line. But Please tell me why is the Image's Width Talking up the Whole width of the Navbar. That is why I still cannot see the Tab's. I have Set the Image width to 10% but it's still talking up the whole width of the navbar.

Comment: That is because the logo is inside the navbar-header. Try removing the styling properties of the image. Then inspect the navbar-header and the navbar-brand. You will see that the navbar-header is taking up the entire width

Comment: Thanks for the Help Kyrul. Appreciate the Help a Lot.

Answer (score 0):

Place your `logo` and `navbar` inside the `.navbar-header` and apply `width:100%` for your header. That will fix the issue.

```
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Images/Rendered-Logo-(Version-2).png" alt="Rendered-Logo" style="width: 10%; height: auto; margin-right: 0;"></a>            
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-left: 0; padding: 5px; font-size: 15px; color: black;">
           <li><a href="#">Couses</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .navbar-header {width:100%;}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mw2L21gL/)

Comment: Unfortunately It still doesn't show up on the same line. It seems that the tabs are underneath the navbar. I have tried setting the overflow to visible and suddenly they appear on the line below. And it seems that even when my logo's width is only 10%, it is talking up the entire width of the navbar. Any Ideas?